# How to overcome from `ssh: connect to host ssh.dev.azure.com port 22: Connection timed out` with VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

I am trying to access my office repo from home, i am getting an error as:

```
ssh: connect to host ssh.dev.azure.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

In office, it works fine. at home I have installed the VPN to connect office network. still not works.

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe VPN network use other addresses then local network in office and this VPN network is not allowed to have access to repository.
Other thing: when you are connected to VPN all traffic is routed via it? Maybe are set access restriction on `ssh.dev.azure.com` in firewall.